# Azure Event Hub : Create Logger - 400 Invalid Hostname

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to create a proof of concept with Azure APIM and am stuck at a 400 invalid hostname error.

I have tried following this example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs

which leads me to this page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/logger/createorupdate

I have in postman the put command with the following url, edited out the personal details

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx-yyyy-zzz-a4ed-b0b5ddddddd/resourceGroups/xx-Trial/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxx-API-Management-Services/loggers/loggerId?api-version=2019-12-01

This is being sent as a PUT command

This is the body that is also being sent

```
{  
 "type": "AzureEventHub",  
 "description": "xx Poc description",  
 "credentials": {  
   "name": "apim",  
   "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://xx-poc.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yyyyyyK/ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxc="  
 }  
}
```

The response that comes back is

```
<h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr>
<p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
```

I would be grateful if anyone can help me progress this forward as I cannot see what I have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching I finally stumbled across this url https://www.svenmalvik.com/azure-apim-with-eventhub/ which has resolve my issue.

I had done everything right in terms of setup, but this was the final step that was missing

```
$apimCtx = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "xx-Trial" -ServiceName "xx-API-Management-Services"
$ehConnection = (Get-AzEventHubKey -ResourceGroupName "xx-Trial" -NamespaceName "xx-yyy-zzz-eh-ns" -AuthorizationRuleName "xx-yyy-zzz-eh-auth-rule").PrimaryConnectionString
New-AzApiManagementLogger -Context $apimCtx -LoggerId "simon-logger" -Name "simon-logger" -ConnectionString "$ehConnection;EntityPath=xx-yyy-eh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there'are something wrong with the request body.

```
{  
 "type": "AzureEventHub",  
 "description": "xx Poc description",  
 "credentials": {  
   "name": "apim",  
   "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://xx-poc.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=yyyyyyK/ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxc="  
 }  
}
```

Please check the following settings in your request body:

1. For **name**, please make sure it's the **Event hub instance name**, not the **Eventhub namespace name**. And you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create#create-an-event-hubs-namespace) for more details about them.
2. For **connectionString**, please make sure it's the **Eventhub namespace connectiong string**(do not use the Eventhub instance level connection string). For more details, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string#get-connection-string-from-the-portal).

At the end, please also check if the eventhub instance is disabled or not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have tried this and still no luck

Comment: still the same, hwever I have just resolve this using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xS_KGuCXVVw

Comment: @SimonPrice, great! You can add an answer for it, or you can edit my answer by adding this solution.